# Why does an isFile filter disagree with a directory listing? (PYTHON)

Tags: python, file, filter, directory

If I get the number of files in a directory (that has 3 folders and 20 files) I get the following behavior for listdir and an isfile, respectively:

```
>>> len(os.listdir('/home/a/Desktop/Development/'))
23

>>> len(filter(os.path.isfile,os.listdir('/home/a/Desktop/Development/')))
7
```

Trying again on a folder that has no subfolders:

```
>>> len(os.listdir('/home/a/Desktop/Development/newfolder'))
38

>>> len(filter(os.path.isfile,os.listdir('/home/a/Desktop/Development/newfolder')))
0
```

Why doesn't listdir provide the same result as an isfile filter?

Comment: Did you run the command without `len` to see what's different?

Answer (score 1):

Because os.listdir returns relative paths. E.g. if you got files a.txt and b.txt it will return "a.txt" and "b.txt". Non zero on first run means you got some files with same names in your pwd.

Comment: I guess you mean `cwd`, not `pwd`.

Comment: Both terms are used.